# Qual a diferença de "zend_extension" e "extension" no php.ini?

Tags: php

Notei que algumas extensões como a Opcache só podem ser ativadas (adicionadas) via `zend_extension`, conforme http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.installation.php:

Plataformas "não Windows":

```
zend_extension=/full/path/to/opcache.so
```

Windows:

```
zend_extension=C:\path\to\php_opcache.dll
```

Gostaria de saber se existe algum motivo especial para isto?

Comment: [PHP vs Zend extensions](https://wiki.php.net/internals/extensions)